# Destination folder will not appear in my desktop using xcopy

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to copy a folder named "quiet" on the same directory as where my batch file would be to my desktop as a folder named "quiet2". I tried using this code:

```
@echo off
xcopy /E /H /K %cd%\quiet\ %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\quiet2\
```

What happens is, the cmd window briefly opens but it doesn't copy the folder to the desktop. Can anyone help?

Comment: Add a `pause` command underneath and it will pause the screen so you can read any messages.

Comment: 1. Quote both source and destination paths! 2. `%CD%` points to the *current working directory*, which is not the same as the parent directory of your batch file; use `%~dp0.` for that...

Comment: Can you accept an answer?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have confused `%~dp0` which represents **d**rive and **p**ath of the 0 argument, which refers to batch file 'identity'. `%cd%` is the current working directory. Use:

```bat
@echo off
xcopy /E /H /K "%~dp0quiet\" "%userprofile%\Desktop\quiet2\"
```